# Selecting fields populated when copying tfs work item

Tags: tfs

New TFS admin here.  A team has requested that when a work item is copied (bug and requirements), the system and referenceid fields should not be copied (i.e. the fields should be blank for all new items).  Any guidance on how to accomplish this?  Seems like making the default value empty would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`DEFAULT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194948(v=vs.100).aspx) rule should work with some restrictions on Area and Iteration fields.
[Work item templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407162(v=vs.100).aspx) may be a better approach for this.

For example, on transition to the first state (`New`, `To Do`, etc.) you can force the default values:

```
 <TRANSITIONS>
    <TRANSITION from="" to="New">
       <FIELDS>
         <FIELD refname="System.AssignedTo">
           <DEFAULT from="value" value="" />
         </FIELD>
         <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.BacklogPriority">
           <DEFAULT from="value" value="100" />
         </FIELD>
       </FIELDS>
  </TRANSITION>
```

Comment: where in the WIT would I make this change?